# rtabmap_ros kitti2rosbag using orb_slam2 as Odometry

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfuly run rtabmap_ros by rosbag created from kitti2rosbag  .Thanks to Mathieu !
But now , when i try to us orb_slam2 as Odometry , i got a lot problems.
I also  successfully compiled RTAB-Map with Orb-Slam2, so I can now choose ORB-SLAM2 as an odometry strategy in RTAB-Map standalone app.
And i try rtabmap_ros and add those code in launch:

```
<param name="Odom/Strategy" value="5"/>
      <param name="OdomORBSLAM2/VocPath" value="/home/harold/slam/SLAM/src/ORB_SLAM2/Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt"/>
      <param name="OdomORBSLAM2/Bf" value="386.1448"/>
      <param name="OdomORBSLAM2/Fps" value="10"/>
      <param name="OdomORBSLAM2/ThDepth" value="35"/>
```

in

```
<node if="$(arg stereo)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="stereo_odometry" name="stereo_odometry" output="$(arg output)" args="$(arg rtabmap_args) $(arg odom_args)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
```

Than i run

```
roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch stereo:="true" left_image_topic:=/kitti/camera_color_left/image_raw right_image_topic:=/kitti/camera_color_right/image_raw left_camera_info_topic:=/kitti/camera_color_left/camera_info right_camera_info_topic:=/kitti/camera_color_right/camera_info rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" approx_sync:=true use_sim_time:=true frame_id:=base_link
rosbag play --clock kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0001_synced.bag
```

Rtabmap only run a piture ,then it stop with:

```
[ WARN] (2019-07-31 10:28:54.911) util3d.cpp:741::cloudFromDisparityRGB() Decimation (4) is not valid for current image size (depth=1238x374). Highest compatible decimation used=2.
```

[ WARN] (2019-07-31 10:28:54.975) util3d.cpp:741::cloudFromDisparityRGB() Decimation (4) is not valid for current image size (depth=1238x374). Highest compatible decimation used=2.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
[ INFO] [1564540134.997072046, 1317275700.364743025]: rtabmap (1): Rate=1.00s, Limit=0.000s, RTAB-Map=0.0958s, Maps update=0.0081s pub=0.0002s (local map=1, WM=1)

```
[ WARN] (2019-07-31 10:28:55.050) util3d.cpp:741::cloudFromDisparityRGB() Decimation (4) is not valid for current image size (depth=1238x374). Highest compatible decimation used=2.
```

[rtabmap/stereo_odometry-2] process has died [pid 28335, exit code -6, cmd /home/harold/slam/rtabmap/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/stereo_odometry --delete_db_on_start left/image_rect:=/kitti/camera_color_left/image_raw right/image_rect:=/kitti/camera_color_right/image_raw left/camera_info:=/kitti/camera_color_left/camera_info right/camera_info:=/kitti/camera_color_right/camera_info rgbd_image:=rgbd_image_relay odom:=odom imu:=/imu/data __name:=stereo_odometry __log:=/home/harold/.ros/log/e4261a2a-b33a-11e9-a93c-086266871209/rtabmap-stereo_odometry-2.log].
log file: /home/harold/.ros/log/e4261a2a-b33a-11e9-a93c-086266871209/rtabmap-stereo_odometry-2*.log\

this is picture:
[image]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329702/rtabmap_ros-kitti2rosbag-using-orb_slam2-as-odometry/) by [lixz123007](https://answers.ros.org/users/44092/lixz123007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you build ORB_SLAM2 from original repo without any changes? If so, you may have to apply this [patch](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matlabbe/c10403c5d44af85cc3585c0e1c601a60/raw/48adf04098960d86ddf225f1a8c68af87bfcf56e/orbslam2_f2e6f51_marchnative_disabled.patch) to disable `-march=native` and rebuild ORB_SLAM2. If you installed PCL from binaries, normally rtabmap won't be built with `-march=native`, so when we use a dependency using it, rtabmap will crash when using Eigen functions. If the patch doesn't help, you may add `--udebug` to `odom_args` to see more logs.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lixz123007](https://answers.ros.org/users/44092/lixz123007/) on 2019-07-31**:
Thank you for saving me again! I ran it successfully!

**Comment by [lixz123007](https://answers.ros.org/users/44092/lixz123007/) on 2019-08-08**:
I really dont want trouble you ,but i meet a big problem again and i dont know how to solve it after check other questions.[this is link!](https://answers.ros.org/question/330157/large-mapor-loopclosure-make-rtabmap_ros-and-the-whole-ubuntu-crash/).
Please have a look ,any suggestion is OK!